# Waveform decoding

Tags: spi, i2c, signal-processing

I am trying to get the information from my mouse's optical sensor, strictly ΔX and ΔY. I looked up the datasheet for the microcontroller that communicates with the optical sensor and all I could find was this. http://www.sunplusit.com/english/products/peripheral/SPCP19E2A.aspx, which states that it has 15 GPIO pins, USB-PS/2, and SPI. Analyzing the pins, I get data when I move the mouse on  4 pins, see attached. If it were SPI, there is supposed to be a SCK (clock) but none of the data is at a set interval. Maybe the clock is negotiated on initialization or hard coded? It looks like the Orange is either chip select or an interrupt. Does anyone know what type of signal this is? It does not look like enough data to be what I am after.  (purple is a continuous cycle, unrelated to the mouse movement.)

[image]

Thank you in advance,
Nick

EDIT:
Ok,
I changed the sample rate to 10Mhz and got a completely different picture. The pink is definitely the chip clock, ranging between 14Mhz and 16Mhz (additional pull at 100Mhz although I could not gather any other data in the 32Mb buffer). As SPI can be run between 4.7K-3Mhz, I think it is irrelevant. On that note, I think there is no clock.

Comment: The uppermost looks like SCK and the second one as SDO. SCK is not necessarily have a fixed frequency, as it is produced by master and consumed by slave.

Comment: Maybe yellow is your clock and you're not sampling fast enough to get it.